# Background Image is not working in css

Tags: html, css, background-image

My background image is failing to load on my website. I checked the inspect option in google chrome and it told me that the path I gave in the is wrong. I put the image in the css folder to check if it was going to work but it didn't. I put it back inside the images folder and tried this:

```
#background1{
background: url(../../images/rusteberg.jpeg);
        }
```

This didn't work either. I am all out of options here.

Comment: can you reach the image via your browser?

Comment: We can't tell what is wrong about the path without knowing what the URLs of all the relevant files are!

Comment: I cant upvote since I don't have 15 reputation but thanks for your help

Comment: The problem was resolved when I copied and pasted the code on to a new file

Answer (score 1):

As a general solution to "invalid pathing" issues on websites, you should be using the base path (preceding slash `/`) for all site-local URLs .

So your CSS rule becomes:

```
#background1{
    background: url('/images/rusteberg.jpeg');
        }
```

Where I have made the assumption that your `images` folder is a direct child of your website address so: `http://www.yourwebsite.org.uk/images/rusteberg.jpeg` would be the working browser URL of the image you want to display.

This means that whatever location your CSS file is, doesn't matter, as the image will always be found because the resource location is now *not relative* to the CSS location.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach to this issue is to use Google Chrome's (or any other in your preference, while I really recommend GC) Inspector, using `Ctrl+Shift+I`.

Then right click on your `<div>` and on the right side, check the

```
background: url( '../../image.jpg' );
```

definition to gain the related image URL, which does not have a correct URL to the image.

Click On that link and let the browser try to open it. there you may have the URL in your browser's address bar like:

```
http://example.com/path///image.jpg
```

There you may compare the given URL with that of your image regarding the relative path of the image.